# Ensuring jQuery AJAX requests are made with with jsFiddle account

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsfiddle

With jsFiddle, an AJAX form is served to the client. I would like to make sure that all AJAX calls are made with the form at `jsfiddle.net/MyUsername`. I would like to validate the requests with PHP on the destination server.

Is it possible ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a header `REFERER`, but it can be omitted or forged, so it's not all that reliable.

There isn't a way to know for sure.

Comment: There is a PHP variable called $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], but it always shows the client's IP from my experience. May be there is some way to include the jsFiddle IP. Of course, including it in the AJAX data is not ideal.

Comment: Same story. These stuff are sent by the browser and the browser can be tinkered with.